# How to remove elements from arraylist in linear time

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity

Great suggestions but some of them were not allowed (as streams), was very restricted task. Leo's algorithm was the thing I was looking for.

I'm trying to compare a specific letter on arraylist elements and need to remove every bigger letter from the arraylist. This has to be done in linear time, so `remove()` is not an option. How do I do it?

```java
int deleted = 0;
int n = 0;

while (n < A.size()) {
    if (A.get(n).compareTo(x) > 0) {
        //removing here
        removed = removed + 1;
    }
    n++;
}

return removed;
```

`A` is an arraylist with random alphabetical letters and `x` is also a random letter. I need to remove every element from `A` which is bigger than the given `x` letter. Remove() is not an option because I need to do this in linear time instead of n^2.

Comment: Is the list sorted?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No it is not sorted and I cant sort it.

Comment: Please add a real [mcve], with example data that we can ideally run to repro the problem you intend to solve.

Comment: @Dici this is homework and im insisted to use arraylist

Comment: count the items you need, create a new arraylist with that size, copy the items.

Comment: @sossu: sorting has a fundamental lower bound of *O(n log n)*, so that would already be too high.

Comment: @k5_: an `ArrayList` has a dynamic size, and the amortized cost makes adding *n* elements linear (see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63752/amortized-time-cost-of-insertion-into-an-array-list) hence, it is sufficient to simply add elements.

Comment: I think the best solution is linear with no extra memory, check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove elements in linear time from the list itself rather than creating a new list, then you can do it like this.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (j < A.size()) {
    if (A.get(j).compareTo(x) > 0) {
        j++;
    } else if (i < j) {
        A.set(i++, A.get(j++));
    } else {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
int oldSize = A.size();
int newSize = oldSize - j + i;
A.subList(newSize, oldSize).clear();
```

This basically runs once through the list, shifting down elements to overwrite the elements that need to be filtered out. Then the list is trimmed down to size in the last three lines.

Comment: Just if you're interested, check my implementation. It's the same idea but perhaps a bit neater.

Comment: @Dici your implementation won't always work, because some lists will throw an exception if you modify them while running through them with an `Iterator` (as your for-each loop does).

Comment: I tested it on an array list, sounds ok. Worst-case scenario the same can be done using a for i ... loop, I don't think any list would complain about that. To be fair this implementation only works well on random access lists, I didn't try to make it good for any list. But in the general case, you might be right. Are you aware of any standard list implementation that wouldn't like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add elements in linear time to **another list**. For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int n = 0; n < A.size(); n++) {
    if(A.get(n).compareTo(x) <= 0) {
        result.add(A.get(n));
    }
}
return result;
```

or with streams as @Dici says:

```
A.stream().filter(n -> n.compareTo(x) <= 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can later swap the lists, or clear the original list, and copy the values from `result` back in that list, which takes linear time as well.

Although using another data structure to store data might be beneficial as well.

Comment: You could also fhow the solution using streams, it's neater! Also, to my knowledge no version of Java supports primitive generics although they want to do it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `SortedSet` to get the set having elements less than the given string, this can be achieved by using the `SortedSet.headSet(String key)` method:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("d");
list.add("l");
list.add("e");
list.add("z");
list.add("x");

SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
String x = "f"; //string to compare
List<String> elementsLessThanX = new ArrayList<>(set.headSet("f")); 
System.out.println(elementsLessThanX);
```

Output:

```
[d, e]
```

This is definitely not constant time but it is better than O(n^2). This implementation would not modify the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's you need?

```
ArrayList<String> b = a.stream().filter(l -> l.compareTo(x) <= 0)
                                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: It's not doing the right thing, the OP wants to remove all elements larger than a given character, not those that are different from it

Answer (score 1):

The least expensive solution is to traverse the list once while incrementing an index that represents the number of elements matching the criterion. Every time an element is found, it is set at this index and the index is incremented. In the end, you just have to delete everything at the right of this index. It's cheap to do so because deleting at the end of an array list is constant time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6, 4, 7, 0, 2));
    filterLargerElementsInPlace(list, 4, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    System.out.println(list); // [1, 3, 0, 2]
}

public static <T> void filterLargerElementsInPlace(List<T> list, T max, Comparator<T> cmp) {
    int i = 0;
    for (T elem : list) {
        if (cmp.compare(elem, max) < 0) {
            // mutating the list as we traverse it, but it's safe as i is always less than the current index
            list.set(i++, elem);
        }
    }
    while (list.size() > i) list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```